# Exporting polygon as DXF using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, export, ogr, dxf

I am working on a script to export my dissolved polygon into Dxf but I get an error.
Could somebody teach me how to do this?

Here is my code:

```py
from qgis import processing
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

inlay = iface.activeLayer()

print("converting to polygon...")

polygonize = processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:polygonize", 

            {'INPUT':inlay,
        'BAND':1,
        'FIELD':'DN',
        'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS':False,
        'EXTRA':'',
        'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

dissolve = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve",
                             {'INPUT':polygonize['OUTPUT'],
                              'FIELD':[],
                              'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

path_file = f'C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads'
date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), "%Y%m%d") # or "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"


archive = path_file +'/'+'HEIC'+ f'{date}' + '.dxf'
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:savefeatures", 
               {'INPUT':dissolve['OUTPUT'],
              'OUTPUT':archive,
               'LAYER_NAME':'',
               'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
               'LAYER_OPTIONS':'',
               'Add_save_file_to_map':True})

print("check your downloads folder..")
print('Done')
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
exec(Path('C:/Users/CMCA/OneDrive - Boskalis/Documents/Trial PyQGIS/Polygonize_tool.py').read_text())
converting to polygon...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 151, in runAndLoadResults
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(alg, parameters=parameters, onFinish=handleAlgorithmResults, feedback=feedback,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 179, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 72, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Could not create layer C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/HEIC20230606.dxf: Creation of field fid failed (OGR error: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'fid' not created.)
```

Comment: change {'INPUT':iface.activeLayer() .. to {'INPUT':dissolve['OUTPUT'] ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expFolder = r"/home/cirrusklaus/Downloads/tmp/shp" #Path of a Linux OS adapt it
Filename= 'myFile'#adapt it
Filetyp='dxf'
filename = f"{Filename}.{Filetyp}"

output = os.path.join(expFolder, filename)#the complete path
print(output)

myLayer = iface.activeLayer()


result1 = processing.run("native:polygonize", 
    {'INPUT':myLayer,
    'KEEP_FIELDS':True,
    'OUTPUT':'OUTPUT'})
ResPolygonize = result1['OUTPUT']
#########################################
#next step dissvole
result2=processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve", 
    {'INPUT':ResPolygonize,
    'FIELD':[],# If you do not define a field the result will be one polygon
    'SEPARATE_DISJOINT':False,
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
ResDis = result2['OUTPUT']
#You can save the result2 Dissolves output as dxf-File
#########################################
#next to dxf
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dxfexport", 
    {'LAYERS':[{'layer': ResDis,
    'attributeIndex': -1}],
    'SYMBOLOGY_MODE':0,
    'SYMBOLOGY_SCALE':1e+06,
    'ENCODING':'cp1250',
    'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:31468'),#you have to change the ESPG
    'USE_LAYER_TITLE':False,
    'FORCE_2D':False,
    'MTEXT':True,

    'OUTPUT':output})

print(f"Done.")
```

Comment: If this corrects the code in your previous answer, please [edit that answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/460881/edit) with the changes, rather than posting an additional answer.

Comment: @klaus how do you change the CRS, if you will use a "USER"

Answer (score 0):

You have to transfer the data to the processingtools with a variable. At the very end you don't have to pass iface but the last step ot the result. Try this:

```
from qgis import processing


inlay = iface.activeLayer()

print("converting to polygon...")

result1 = processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:polygonize", 
    {'INPUT':inlay,
    'BAND':1,
    'FIELD':'DN',
    'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS':False,
    'EXTRA':'',
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
ResPolygonize = result1['OUTPUT']
#########################################
#next step dissvole
reslut2=dissolve = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve",
    {'INPUT':ResPolygonize,
    'FIELD':[],
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
ResDiss = result2['OUTPUT']
#########################################
#next dxf-export
archive = path_file +'/'+'CDC+HEIC_2ndFill_'+ f'{date}' + '.dxf'
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:savefeatures", 
    {'INPUT':ResDiss,
    'OUTPUT':archive,
    'LAYER_NAME':'',
    'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
    'LAYER_OPTIONS':'',
    'Add_save_file_to_map':True})
print("check your downloads folder..")
print('Done')
```

Comment: hi , I edited my script above and it error message said it "does not support .dxf"

Comment: in result 1 is an error, I have changed it.